# Azure Data Factory For-Each Activity iteration is failing, but pipeline succeeded?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have one For-Each Activity, which iterates 4 times. Out of those 4 runs, one of the run failed, but still the pipeline is shown as succeeded ?

Comment: Thats a strange behaviour. I have a ADF pipeline which looks up list of tables to be imported from a file in blob, then for each entry in the file, fetches data from blob and copies it to SQL DB. If any of the copy job fails, then pipeline is marked as Failed. Can you elaborate what exactly ur pipeline is doing and share some screenshots as well.

Comment: @Pushkin This thread helped me to resolve the issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/63999